# (Pdb) coming up when executing python script

Tags: python, linux

I have a werid issue with a Python script. I already asked the developer of that script, unfortunately he did not gave any helpful answer besides telling me that it "should work fine".

The script is [this one](https://github.com/monitisexchange/Monitis-Linux-Scripts/blob/master/nginx/python/nginx_stubstatus.py) and is also importing [this one](https://github.com/monitisexchange/Monitis-Linux-Scripts/blob/master/nginx/python/sdk/monitisserver.py).

When I try to use it (filled my data in) it runs for a sec and then:

```
> /opt/monitis_nginx_monitoring/sdk/monitisserver.py(84)monitisPost()
-> postArgs['timestamp'] = self.timestamp()
(Pdb)
```

Comes up and is waiting for an user input. Not too familar with pythhon, but this appears to be the debugger, so something seems to be wrong.

When I type in `postArgs` it is showing all expected post arguments, besides the timestamp, the timestamp is not included in the post data, so it looks like that something goes wrong with the timestamp. However, when I type in `timestamp()` it is outputting a correct timestamp.

Any idea what is wrong with this script?

**Update:** Just removed the debugger statement, now something else goes wrong:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "nginx_stubstatus.py", line 139, in <module>
    result=result, checkTime=None)
  File "/opt/monitis_nginx_monitoring/sdk/monitisserver.py", line 129, in addResult
    monitorId = self.requestMonitorId(monitorTag)
  File "/opt/monitis_nginx_monitoring/sdk/monitisserver.py", line 40, in requestMonitorId
    return root.find('./monitor/id').text
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Comment: Seems like the developer left a debugger statement in. You should just remove it.

Comment: Just saw your comment, I will do, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Line 83 of monitisserver.py: `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()`.

This causes python to break into the debugger (pdb) on this line.

---

Tell the maintainer about this. This should not be in production code without any condition (i.e debug mode)

Comment: Thanks, I will do, not sure though if they care. Can I safely remove this line to get it working? Thanks a lot, Sebastian!

Comment: @Michael Yes you can safely remove that line

Comment: Alright, just did. Unfortunately now something else seems to be wrong, see my edit :(

Comment: I assume it has something to do with root.find('./monitor/id'), not sure though what this is supposed to do? Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: @Michael This is some bug on their side. `root.find('./monitor/id').text` doesn't perform any nilcheck as proper code should. I guess the breakpoint was left in the code because it's not working at the moment?